# how do i using mysql join to arrange conversations with latest reply

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

we have two tables, screenshot attached

[image: this image contains every single piece of message sent]

this table named as messages

[image: this image contacts details of a every conversation started by a student to teacher]

this table is named as conversations

Now every time a student sends a message, the conversations tables checks if conversation exists via `convo` unique id, and then puts the message on database with `sender_id` as the unique id of student `receiver_id` as the unique id of teacher, `convo` as the conversation_id which is unique for every single student and teacher conversation.

What we want to do is, we want to display conversations like facebook, latest conversation with latest message is going to be at the top, we are going to find latest message with created_at, and of course student can only see conversations he started, help us, we are stuck here, unable to write a proper mysql query for it, we are using codeigniter framework for our back end

So far we came up with this, but seems like not working

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from($this->conversation_table_name);
$this->db->join($this->message_table_name,'conversation.convo = messages.convo');
$this->db->where('conversation.student',$student_number);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Looks like you might just need to set an order, using `$this->db->order_by("created_at", "desc");`  That will order the messages by created time, with newest first

Comment: Yes, you need to set an order by (either by the created_at or by the id field) in DESC order.  Also, I am not sure I would use a varchar as my join field.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from($this->conversation_table_name);
$this->db->join($this->message_table_name,'conversation.convo = messages.convo');
$this->db->where('conversation.student',$student_number);
$this->db->group_by("conversation.sender_id");
$this->db->order_by("messages.created_at", "desc"); 
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: hi this solution is working, may i know how would can i get teacher name from table teachers? simple column is like teachers.teacher_name, it has unique teacher_id

Comment: First add the teacher_id in message table. Then before the where condition add $this->db->join($this->teachers_table_name,'messages.teacher_id' = 'teachers.teacher_id');